# google video intelligence python tutorial : where to place credential key.json?

Tags: python, video-intelligence-api

I have forked python - doc - sample
https://github.com/aliwo/python-docs-samples

and I'm trying to learn .py file below.
python-docs-samples\video\cloud-client\labels\labels.py

error message occured:

```
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically     determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or
explicitly create credential and re-run the application. For more
information, please see
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials.
```

I checked all the google client website but could not find where to place my service account's key.json file.
how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 2):

If you are running the code on your local machine, you should be able to put the key.json file anywhere and follow the "Authenticating with Application Default Credentials" step on [this page](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/common/auth) (on the bottom of the page).

Specifically:

```
$ export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<path_to_service_account_file>
```

Comment: In window, how can I do that?

Comment: I managed it in control panel - system environment variable. Thanks!

Comment: Great!  It seems that doing the following in the command line should also work:

`C:\> set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<path_to_service_account_file>`

Comment: @ dizcology I thought variable set by 'set' command doesn't last after cmd session is closed. Did you try that after rebboting?

Comment: You are most definitely right - I saw that instruction in one of the documentations and simply put it here just in case it might be useful for someone.

Answer (score 2):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVKZG.jpg)

control panel -> system environment variable -> set like this